# Creating Generic Windows Form

Tags: c#, winforms

At my job I find myself creating the same style of windows form often. I would like to move out the repeated code and create a template to start out new projects with.

```
 public partial class GenericForm<T> : Form
{

  private void InitializeComponent()
    {
     .
     .
     .
        this.pbProduction.Image = ((System.Drawing.Image)(resources.GetObject("pbProduction.Image")));

      }
```

I get an error when trying to load an image

```
     {"Could not find any resources appropriate for the specified culture or the neutral culture. 
 Make sure \"SplitForm.GenericForm`1.resources\" was correctly embedded or linked into assembly \"SplitForm\" 
at compile time, or that all the satellite assemblies required are loadable and fully signed."}
```

where am I going wrong with this?

[project Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/imkcl.png)

Answer (score 0):

From your project structure, you haven't added your image as a ressource to your project.  Since Properties folder is not expanded, I can't tell if you have a Ressources.resx file in your project or not.

You should:

- right click your poject and clic Properties
- Go To the Ressources tab, create a ressources file  if not already done
- Add your image as a Resource (change ressource type from Strings to Images 
  and browse to your image)
- Now you should be able to access the added ressource using

  this.pbProduction.Image = Properties.Resources.MyImageName

more info can be found on the microsoft website
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3bka19x4(v=vs.100).aspx

Answer (score 0):

I know what's wrong!!! I've tested generic classes before answering this question!

#### First step

You already have made this step.

Make your regular class generic.

```
public partial class GenericForm<T> : Form
{
    private void InitializeComponent()
    {
        this.pbProduction.Image = ((System.Drawing.Image)(resources.GetObject("pbProduction.Image")));
    }
}
```

#### Second step

Make your `GenericForm.Designer.cs` generic too, it seems your partial class is inconsistent, both classes should be generic

```
partial class GenericForm<T>
{
    //Don't touch the rest of the designer's code
}
```

#### Third step

**IMPORTANT:** Skip this step if your form is not the entry point.

If your form is shown when your application starts, you'll need to modify the `Program.cs` to add the generic class, for example, let's use a `string`.

```
static class Program {
    [STAThread]
    static void Main() {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        Application.Run(new GenericForm<string>());
    }
}
```

#### About your resources issue

This is not how the resources work!!! If you want to use an image from your resources, use the following code:

```
Properties.Resources.<here's your resource's name>
```

You don't need to use the `.resx` file directly. Simply add your images in Project >  Properties > Resources.
The `.resx` file was designed for visual designer, not for code.